# remove parent's parent or specific tag

Tags: jquery, dom

I have some generated output like this:

```
<figure>
    <a href="location.php"><img src=""></a>
</figure>
```

and when I apply this JS:

```
$(funciton() {
    $('img').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('src') == null || $(this).attr('src') == '')
            { 
                $(this).parent().remove();
            }
});
```

It removes the img tag, and it's parent a tag but leaves this output on the page:

```
<figure>
"&#8203"            ​
</figure>
```

How can I remove the paren't 's parent  tag or just trim it so there is no blank entity present? When there is anything in the figure tag it has a 1px height and margin from css. I can change css, but want to figure this out, help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the parent `<figure>` tag is empty if the image tag has no `.src`, you can do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        if(!this.src) { 
            $(this).closest("figure").empty();
        }
     }
});
```

`.empty()` removes all childnodes and any text in the element.

Note, I also simplified your comparison on `.src`.  First off, there's no need to use jQuery here and second off, a single test can check for any empty value.

If you really want the `<figure>` tag to take up no space on the page, you might also just do a `.hide()` on it.

Comment: Great, the .closest was what I needed. I used .remove() rather than empty() although both worked to some extent.

Comment: Also, simplifying the .src comparison didn't work. Had to use the long drawn out way.